# how can I make my own custum registration, login form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner for MVC. I have started a new MVC4 project using the Internet Application template by using Visual Studio 2012. I started by modifying deafult template to make registration, login, form and connected with database table which I have created in sql serever express 2012 by using Entity framework and by changing connect string. It is connected with database and atomatically add those table available by defuault in to my database.

```
[dbo].[System_Users]

[dbo].[UserProfile]

[dbo].[webpages_Membership]

[dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership]

[dbo].[webpages_Roles]

[dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
```

When I checked by putting some data in registor form it does not save on my registration database table.

How will I solve this problem? am in the right way start working on Internet Application template and modifying it?